# How can I display the input in another screen in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a multiple screen code to calculate the amount of paint needed to paint a room.

There's a screen where I want to display the user inputs from the previous screen.

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    panjang= float
    lebar= float
    tingi= float
    luas1 = (panjang*tinggi)/10
    luas2= (lebar*tinggi)/10
    cat= luas1*2+luas2*2

    def logOut(self):
        sm.current = "create"

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.panjang.text = "Panjang: " + panjang
        self.lebar.text = "Lebar: " + lebar
        self.tinggi.text = "Tinggi: " + tinggi
```

KV file:

```
<MainWindow>:
    panjang:panjang
    lebar: lebar
    tinggi:tinggi

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: panjang
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Panjang: "

        Label:
            id: lebar
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.7}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Lebar: "

        Label:
            id: tinggi
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.5}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Tinggi:"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint:0.6,0.2
            text: "Semula"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "create"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
```

The input won't show and an error message displayed saying, "panjang is not defined". How can I fix this? And by the look of my coding can luas1, 2 and cat be calculated?

Edit:
I just realized that these lines came out in the error message:

```
 78:
      79:<MainWindow>:
 >>   80:    panjang:panjang
      81:    lebar: lebar
      82:    tinggi:tinggi
```

Then I tried adding space and added the other variebles like this:

```
panjang: panjang
    lebar: lebar
    tinggi: tinggi
    luas1: luas1
    luas2: luas2
    cat: cat
```

Then, these lines came out:

```
 2:    name: "create"
       3:
 >>    4:    panjang: panjang
       5:    lebar: lebar
       6:    tinggi: tinggi
```

Why is there error only in that variable?

Edit2 :

Full python coding:

```
# main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from database import DataBase
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    panjang = ObjectProperty(None)
    lebar = ObjectProperty(None)
    tinggi = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        if self.tinggi.text !="":
            try:
                if float(self.tinggi.text) and float(self.lebar.text) and float(self.panjang.text):

                    sm.current = "main"

            except:
                invalidForm()

        else:
            invalidForm()


    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "main"

    def reset(self):
        self.panjang.text = ""
        self.lebar.text = ""
        self.tinggi.text = ""

class MainWindow(Screen):
    # Each screen has by default a property manager that gives 
    # you the instance of the ScreenManager used.

    # declare class attributes
    panjang = ObjectProperty(None)
    lebar = ObjectProperty(None)
    tingi = ObjectProperty(None)

    # declare and initialize to 0.0 (float)
    luas1 = NumericProperty(0.0)
    luas2 = NumericProperty(0.0)
    cat = NumericProperty(0.0)

    def logOut(self):
        self.manager.current = "create"

    def volume(self):
        self.luas1 = float(self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text) * float(self.tinggi) / 10
        self.luas2 = (self.lebar * self.tinggi) / 10
        self.cat = self.luas1*2 + self.luas2*2

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.volume()    # calculate volume
        self.panjang.text = "Panjang: " + self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text
        self.lebar.text = "Lebar: " + self.manager.ids.create.lebar.text
        self.tinggi.text = "Tinggi: " + self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text
        self.luas1.text = "Luas:" + self.manager.ids.main.luas1.text
        self.luas2.text = "Luas:" + self.manager.ids.main.luas2.text
        self.cat.text = "Luas:" + self.manager.ids.main.cat.text


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def invalidLogin():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                  content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


def invalidForm():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Form',
                  content=Label(text='Please fill in all inputs with valid information.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    pop.open()


kv = Builder.load_file("banyaknyakerja.kv")

sm = WindowManager()

screens = [CreateAccountWindow(name="create"),MainWindow(name="main")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "create"


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Full KV coding:

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    CreateWindow:
        id:create
        name: "create"

    MainWindow:
        id: main
        name: "main"

<CreateAccountWindow>:

    panjang: panjang
    lebar: lebar
    tinggi: tinggi

    FloatLayout:
        cols:1

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Label:
                text: "serfbgokmfor"
                size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
                pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":1}
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
                text: "Panjang: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.8}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.12
                id: panjang
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8-0.13}
                text: "Lebar: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.8-0.13}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.12
                id: lebar
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8-0.13*2}
                text: "Tinggi:"
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.8-0.13*2}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.12
                id: tinggi
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.3,"y":0.25}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 17**4
            text: "Fefrkglt;mlfavsmdmcfr"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.login()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.15
            text: "Kira"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.submit()



<MainWindow>:
    panjang: panjang
    lebar: lebar
    tinggi: tinggi
    luas1: luas1
    luas2: luas2
    cat: cat

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: panjang
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Panjang: "

        Label:
            id: lebar
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.8}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Lebar: "

        Label:
            id: tinggi
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.7}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Tinggi:"

        Label:
            id: luas1
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.6}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Luas:"

        Label:
            id: luas2
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.5}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Luas:"

        Label:
            id: cat
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "top":0.4}
            size_hint:0.8, 0.2
            text: "Cat:"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint:0.6,0.2
            text: "Semula"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "create"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could please share your kv file for `MainWindow`?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the kv file

Comment: I've altered a lot of things but it only said that panjang variable had an error

Comment: @daunfifi123c456b you can not change the content of the question without justifying, if you have another question then create another post. Read [ask]. also do not put deadlines in SO, that is the limit of your work but it is not our deadline since the questions can be solved in 1min, 1 hour, 1 day, 1 month, 1 year or never and that does not depend on your deadline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem 1

> `panjang` is not defined

### Root Cause

The error appeared because when your app tried to access / reference an attribute / variable that is not defined locally in the method `on_enter()`.

### Solution

To access input values from another screen, you need to link the screens to the ScreenManager by doing the following:

1. Assign `id:` to each screens in the kv file
2. ***Kv File:*** Access input values in `<CreateWindow>:` from `<MainWindow>:`,  use `root.manager.ids.create.ids.panjang.text` (using all `ids`) or `root.manager.ids.create.panjang.text` (using a mixture of `ids` and `ObjectProperty`)
3. ***Py File:*** Access input values in `<CreateWindow>:` from `<MainWindow>:`,  use `self.manager.ids.create.ids.panjang.text` (using all `ids`) or `self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text` (using a mixture of `ids` and `ObjectProperty`)

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<WindowManager>:
    CreateAccountWindow:
        id: create
        name: 'create'

    MainWindow:
        id: main
        name: 'main'

<CreateAccountWindow>:
    ...
<MainWindow>:
    ...
```

### Snippets

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    self.panjang.text = "Panjang: " + self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text
    self.lebar.text = "Lebar: " + self.manager.ids.create.lebar.text
    self.tinggi.text = "Tinggi: " + self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text
```

## Problem 2

> can luas1, 2 and cat be calculated?

### Solution

Yes, they can be calculated.

- Implement a method `volume()` and put your formula in it
- Invoke the new method whenever you need to calculate the volume of paint

### Snippets

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
...

class MainWindow(Screen):
    # Each screen has by default a property manager that gives 
    # you the instance of the ScreenManager used.

    # declare class attributes
    panjang = ObjectProperty(None)
    lebar = ObjectProperty(None)
    tingi = ObjectProperty(None)
    luas1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    luas2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    cat = ObjectProperty(None)

    def logOut(self):
        self.manager.current = "create"

    def volume(self):
        luas1 = float(self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text) * float(self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text) / 10
        luas2 = float(self.manager.ids.create.lebar.text) * float(self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text) / 10

        self.luas1.text = str(luas1)
        self.luas2.text = str(luas2)
        self.cat.text = str(luas1 * 2 + luas2 * 2)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.volume()    # calculate volume
        self.panjang.text = "Panjang: " + self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text
        self.lebar.text = "Lebar: " + self.manager.ids.create.lebar.text
        self.tinggi.text = "Tinggi: " + self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text
```

## Output

[image: MainWindow displayed]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work. This error message comes out.

Comment: ValueError: MainWindow.panjang has an invalid format (got <WeakProxy to <kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x000001D062097A70>>)
   File "C:\Users\dekmeymey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 696, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 35, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 497, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 526, in kivy.properties.Property.set

Comment: File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 657, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.convert

Comment: this is the coding around line 35.

Comment: def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "main"

    def reset(self):
        self.panjang.text = ""
        self.lebar.text = ""
        self.tinggi.text = ""

Comment: And I don't know where the hell line 497, 526 and 657 come from

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. But now it said variable luas1 is in the wrong format. What should I do?

Comment: Please share your code in share drive or update your post, Kivy log, and python trace back so that we can re-create the problem, and analyse the problem.

Comment: I added the full coding

Comment: In kv file, replace `ScreenManagement` with `WindowManager`, and `CreateWindow` with `CreateAccountWindow`. In py file, replace `NumericProperty(0.0)` with `ObjectProperty(None)` for `luas1`, `luas2`, and `cat`. There are changes in method `volume()`. Please refer to updated post for details.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm really sorry to burden you but now... the error message stated that this line had a problem

luas1 = float(self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text) * float(self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text) / 10
        luas2 = float(self.manager.ids.create.lebar.text) * float(self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text) / 10

Comment: You encountered, `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` after pressing the button, `Fefrkglt;mlfavsmdmcfr`. This is because in your app, it invoked method `login()`, invoked method `reset()` to reset the input to empty strings, and then switched to screen, `MainWindow`. I believed that there is a logic problem here i.e. when there are no input values, you should not go to `MainWindow`.

Comment: i deleted that reset and login line and this message still appear
line 60, in on_enter
     self.volume()    # calculate volume
   File "C:\Users\dekmeymey\.kivy\banyaknyekerja.py", line 52, in volume
     luas1 = float(self.manager.ids.create.panjang.text) * float(self.manager.ids.create.tinggi.text) / 10
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
>>>

Comment: I found the problem. It's either def on_enter or *args. But I don't know what to change it into.

Comment: I tried changing it, no error message but also no output

Comment: I will make another question